# Index several tables at once with mongoDB, how?

Tags: mongodb, for-loop

I'm trying to create indexes for several tables at once. I currently use a for-loop to create this effect but obviously my for-loop doesn't work.

```
for(i=3;i<8;i++) { db.events_i.ensureIndex({userid:1, numid:1}); };
```

How can I fix this? :)

Comment: By learning basic JS and the attitude to check your JS API of MongoDB first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for(var i = 3; i < 8; i++) { 
    db.getCollection('events_' + i).ensureIndex({userid: 1, numid: 1}); 
};
```

Comment: Is this solution retrieving data? Because the collections is some million rows each. :)

Comment: No, it's not retrieving any data. It's the same as `db.events_1`, but it allows dynamic names.